# Scraping BTC price with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am currently trying to scrape the price of Bitcoin from a website using Python. However, the function is returning 'None' and I am not sure why.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request 
import re 

def scraper():

    r = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.kitco.com/bitcoin-price-charts-usd/").read()
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

    btcPrice = soup.find('div', class_= 'tv-widget-watch-list__last js-symbol-last apply-overflow-tooltip')

    return btcPrice

def main():

    print(f"{scraper()}")

main()
```

Output:

```
None
```

I think this problem may be to do with the html parser, or simply using the wrong tags for the information I need. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `r`?

Comment: Looks like the site uses JavaScript which runs in the web browser to populate the HTML. You can't use BeautifulSoup as is. I think there's an extension to it which works with JavaScript.

Comment: You probably need [tag:selenium]: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: tradingview : Data are transmitted throught websockets.